# Rails APP_PATH's Test dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, testunit

I have the following test:

```
def test_to_show_warnings_if_app_path_is_defined                                      
  require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../lib/macros.rb'
  warnings = $stderr.string.split(/\n/)
  warnings.each { |w| assert_no_match(/warning: already initialized constant/, w) }
end
```

It should fail if there are warnings about already initialized constants. On the other side inside the required file I have the following problem:

```
MYPATH = ""
MYPATH = File.expand_path(File.split(APP_PATH)[0] + "/macros",  __FILE__) if defined?(APP_PATH)
```

It checks if the APP_PATH is defined and saves on MYPATH. Clearly if APP_PATH is defined it will overwrite the constant. I can't correct the code above **unless the test capture this warning**. What should I do?

Remember that APP_PATH is defined when the rails server is running as you can see [here in section 1.3 script/rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html)